# RegEx validation of html form in external .js

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

I am trying to validate a html form using a javascript function, but the function is never matching the values to regex even when they are correct.  This is what I have:

```
function validateForms(form){
var usZipRegex = '^\d{5}[[$-.+ ]?\d{4}]?$|^\d{5}$';
var canZipRegex = '^[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVWXY][\d][ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVWXYZ][\W]?[\d][ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVWXYZ][\d]$';
var nameRegex = '^[A-Za-z][ -a-zA-Z]+$';
var emailRegex = '^[^\.@]([\w]*\.)*[^\.@]*@[a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,63}(\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,63})+$';
var name = form.name.value;
var zip = form.zip.value;
var email = form.email.value;
var comment = form.comment.value
if(name == "") {
  alert('You must enter your name.');
  return false;
}
if(name != nameRegex) {
  alert('You have entered an invalid name.');
  return false;
}
 if(email == "") {
  alert('You must enter your email.');
  return false;
}
if(email != emailRegex) {
 alert('You have entered an invalid email.');
 return false;
}
  if(zip == "") {
  alert('You must enter your zip code.');
  return false;
}
if((zip != usZipRegex) & (zip != canZipRegex)) {
 alert('You have entered an invalid zip code.');
 return false;
}
 if(comment == "") {
 alert('You must enter a message.');
 return false;
}
return true;
}
```

The (name != nameRegex) parts always return true, but should not.  The (name == "") parts do work on their own though.

Comment: just to be sure - you don't use `alert`s in your production code, right?

Answer (score 3):

You're comparing the raw strings, not running the regex. `name != nameRegex` will always return true unless the person's name is literally `^[A-Za-z][ -a-zA-Z]+$`. You need to set up `nameRegex` properly as a regex object, but in your code, it's just a string. You also need to use `test` or another one of the RegExp object's methods to check for a match, not the ==/!= operators. This is true for the other patterns as well.

Constructing a regex is done one of two ways:

```
var regex1 = /[a-z0-9]/;
var regex2 = new RegExp('[a-z0-9]');
```

If you do it like this, though, it's just a string:

```
var notARegex = '[a-z0-9]';
```

#### Your code should be closer to this style:

```
var nameRegex = /^[A-Za-z][-a-zA-Z ]+$/; //note that the hyphen has been moved
//...
if (!nameRegex.test(name)) {
   alert('You have entered an invalid name.');
   return false;
}
```

---

#### Edit: There's more going wrong here. Your other regex code could use some major improvements:

```
var usZipRegex = /^\d{5}([$.+ -]?\d{4})?$/;
var canZipRegex = /^(?![DFIOQU])[A-Y]\d(?![DFIOQU])[A-Z]\W?\d(?![DFIOQU])[A-Z]\d$/;
var nameRegex = /^[a-z][a-z\s-]+$/i;
var emailRegex = /^[^.@]+@[^.@]{1,63}(\.[^.@]{1,63})+$/i';
```

I don't know if your Canadian zip code pattern is correct, but the email one was definitely wrong (email is WAY more complicated than you think, so it's best to be very permissive with it).

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me, I am still getting no matches.

Comment: @user1357071 - What name are you testing this with? The above code works correctly on jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RSCB3/

Comment: I tested a few, including 'foo bar' and it says everything is invalid.

If I put in regex to match anything it will take it ("^[A-z].*","), but not with mine.  I am fairly certain my regex is accurate though.

Comment: @user1357071 - If you follow the jsFiddle link above, you can see "foo bar" working with the code I posted. Here is a simplified version using only that code: http://jsfiddle.net/2R4Np/ If it still doesn't work, please examine my answer for the other problems in your code.

Comment: Just tested in IE and it works, so this code works just fine in my mind.  Anybody have ideas why it doesn't run in FF?

Comment: Your regexes are inaccurate for a few reasons, but one of them is that `[ -a-zA-Z]` isn't valid regex. To be interpreted literally, a hyphen has to be at the beginning or end of a character class: `[- a-zA-Z]` or `[ a-zA-Z-]`. I'm running it in FF and Chrome and both are fine with my code.